# Add one more context to "Active"

Tags: feature-request, bug, localization, russian-stackoverflow

Currently there are two sentences with "Active" word in Transifex:

- [for any purpose](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/$?q=key%3A4d3d769b812b6faa6b76e1a8abaece2d) (no `refersTo` option). Used in question list.
- [for bounties](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/$?q=key%3Ab3985eed93632965fdfd52ffdfb19836%7CrefersTo=bounties) (`refersTo=bounties`)

We need one more that now is used in profile preferences, in particular for a Custom Question Lists to make a suitable/better translation:

> [image: CQL]

Could this please be added.

Comment: Agreed. We also struggled with this very case in [es.so]